# pop shell in linux mint xfce edition

Tags: linux, linux-mint, desktop-customization, window-manager, pop-os

I like the way windows tiles on Pop Os and I want to bring that feature into LinuxMint. When I did my research, most of the tutorials talk about this with Gnome Desktop Environment. I am using Linux Mint XFCE4. Is it possible to install popshell on xfce4 linuxmint. How to do that?

Comment: The easiest way is to use a version of Linux that runs xfce.  I use xfce and like it a lot.